# could not run an angular 2 application in VS 2015

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I want to create an environment on VS 2015 using angular2. when I type"npm start" then I found an error below. I also use "npm cache clean --force " before type"npm start" but found the same error.seems to be I found a similar answer to this problem" [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43600838/failed-at-the-angular-quickstart1-0-0-build-script-tsc-p-src/43600902#43600902"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43600838/failed-at-the-angular-quickstart1-0-0-build-script-tsc-p-src/43600902#43600902%22) but here I did not understand where should I changed to solving it.

```
C:\Users\Hp>cd c:\Users\Hp\Desktop\angular\Angular3Demo\Angular3Demo

c:\Users\Hp\Desktop\angular\Angular3Demo\Angular3Demo>npm start

> angular-quickstart@1.0.0 prestart c:\Users\Hp\Desktop\angular\Angular3Demo\Angular3Demo
> npm run build


> angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build c:\Users\Hp\Desktop\angular\Angular3Demo\Angular3Demo
> tsc -p src/

node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(20,1): error TS1084: Invalid 'reference' directive syntax.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build: `tsc -p src/`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-25T20_05_32_810Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 prestart: `npm run build`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 prestart script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-25T20_05_32_902Z-debug.log

c:\Users\Hp\Desktop\angular\Angular3Demo\Angular3Demo>
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p src/",
    "build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
    "build:e2e": "tsc -p e2e/",
    "serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
    "serve:e2e": "lite-server -c=bs-config.e2e.json",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "pree2e": "npm run build:e2e",
    "e2e": "concurrently \"npm run serve:e2e\" \"npm run protractor\" --kill-others --success first",
    "preprotractor": "webdriver-manager update",
    "protractor": "protractor protractor.config.js",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "test": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "pretest:once": "npm run build",
    "test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/core": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/http": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/router": "~4.3.4",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "~2.1.0",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

I am a beginner, please help.

Comment: Did you check the log file at C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-25T20_05_32_902Z-debug.log

Comment: your `package.json` seems ok try to remove the `node_modules` folder and `npm install` the project again

Comment: @AmitKumarSingh I do that show to my AppData folder.still not working.I don't understand what's the solution this?

Comment: @ajvg94 not working, same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
npm run serve
```

After hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>, it works for me.